# Tons SIT usando Python ou C#

Tags: c#, python, áudio

Olá,
 Estou fazendo um app que detecta os SIT tones (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_information_tones).
 Eu entendo muito pouco a matemática envolvida em transformadas de Fourier e no processamento de sinais.
 O que estou querendo é entender como posso identificar se esses padrões ocorreram em uma chamada voip. Para testar, estou utilizando um arquivo gravado.
 Já tentei entender alguns algoritmos para identificação de frequências, mas preciso pegar tal qual como descrito no link da wikipedia. Ou seja: verificar se ocorreram três toques com aquelas frequências específicas naquela duração específica, com aquele intervalo específico. Tudo o que consegui até agora foi identificar que a frequência ocorre no áudio, mas não consegui descobrir como ver se ocorreu durante o período correto de tempo. (cada código possui uma sequência permutada das mesmas frequências)
 Alguém tem alguma ideia de como eu poderia resolver isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algoritmos de frequências vão te mostrar qual é a frequência fundamental do bloco analisado, você vai precisar saber quais frequências compõem o audio como um todo, eu recomendo fortemente que você entenda a matemática por trás de [Fourier](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformada_de_Fourier), você tem dois caminhos para identificar as frequências:

- Aplicar `FFT`, utilize blocos de tamanhos fixos, esse tamanho vai te
  dizer a duração de cada bloco de análise, se um sinal está amostrado
  a `8000 Hz` então um bloco de análise de tamanho `4096` vai te dar
  `4096/8000 = 512 ms` de análise, pode ser computacionalmente pouco
  eficiente fazer isso para o que você precisa, mas isso vai te dar um
  raio X de todas as frequências contidas no sinal dentro deste bloco,
  as frequências que você procura são senoides e neste caso você deve
  procurar dentro do retorno do FFT se as senoides do seu interesse possuem  amplitude maior que `n dB` e que todas as outras senoides estejam nulas ou abaixo de determinada amplitude de seu interesse.
- OK eu te mostrei como fazer isso meio que na força bruta, a maneira
  realmente eficiente de achar suas frequências é utilizar o algoritmo
  de [Goertzel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goertzel_algorithm), com ele você vai estar exclusivamente olhando
  para as frequências de seu interesse e não dentro de todo o
  espectro.

Python pode realmente tornar as coisas fáceis, utilizar SciPy/NumPy vai te ajudar muito nas análises.

Comment: Olá, @ederwander. Já fiz uma tentativa utilizando goertzel, mas ele informa a frequência e todas as ocorrências dela (não sei como funciona a distribuição das ocorrências), não a duração dessa frequência nem os intervalos.
 Pelo pouco que entendo de fourier, ele pega uma onda e a decompõe em senóides de diferentes tamanhos e/ou pontos de ocorrência. Como preciso identificar se ocorreu um toque de três frequências distintas com duração e intervalo específicos, acredito que preciso pegar os dois pontos em que a senoide toca o eixo x  (tempo?) para uma frequência específica. Ideias?

Comment: Eu utilizei Eu utilizei esse script python para verificar se a frequência ocorre ou não: https://gist.github.com/sebpiq/4128537. Ele me retorna todas as ocorrências da frequência.

Comment: Fiz um teste com esse mesmo algorítimo utilizando dois arquivos diferentes. Um que possui os tons e outro que não possui. Para os dois casos, ele retornou os coeficientes maiores que zero.
 Inclusive, estive pensando que esses tons (SIT) não são como os DTMF que são a soma de duas frequências. Os SIT são uma sequência de três tons específicos.

Comment: oi @DiogoPaschoal sim Goertzel é muito utilizado para encontrar DTMFs, para o seu caso ele vai funcionar muito bem, uma das maneiras de traçar mais ou menos a duração de uma determinada frequência é separar o sinal em blocos de tamanhos fixos por exemplo `2048/8000 =  256ms`, ou seja envie 2048(256ms) amostras para goertzel até o final de todo o seu sinal, você vai ter que ir caminhando com um for, reparou quem 256ms esta abaixo do tempo necessário `Short duration = 276 ms` isso quer dizer q na próxima amostra você ainda terá que procurar se ainda tem a frequência anterior e uma nova .

Comment: Eu dei exemplo de enviar `2048` amostras, mas se o seu sinal for amostrado a 8000hz o tamanho `1024` vai funcionar muito bem para o que precisa. vamos aos cálculos. `8000/1024 = 128ms` isso quer dizer que a mesma frequência em `Short duration` tem que aparecer duas vezes ao enviar duas amostras seguidas `128+128 = 256ms`, e uma frequencia em `Long duration` tem que aparecer 3 vezes seguidas `128*3 = 384ms`, não esqueça de considerar os silêncios nos seus cálculos ai...

Comment: Obrigado, @ederwander. Já estou estudando um material que encontrei em http://professor.ufabc.edu.br/marcio.eisencraft/pds/pds.htm pra entender, mas sua explicação de como obter as amostras já ajudou bastante. Vou tentar aplicar com o que já encontrei.

Answer (score 0):

Realmente eu nunca precisei fazer isso mas eu começaria buscando por uma biblioteca de áudio, como [pyaudio](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/).

Se ela não possuir algo que já resolva seu problema, outra opção é usar **SciPy**/**NumPy** para calcular as transformadas (FFT) e analisar as frequências da amostra.

Comment: Olá, @sergiopereira.
 Eu utilizei o scipy/numpy com o script de goetzerl que copiei no comentário acima, mas preciso ainda entender os tempos e durações.

Comment: @DiogoPaschoal honestamente, eu não sei. Já se vão 20 anos que estudei isso na faculdade e a única vez que trabalhei com telefonia tínhamos hardware que fazia essa deteção e o programa recebia um callback. O melhor que posso sugerir é [esse post so SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2649540/21420)