# O que são os dados obtidos por scipy.io.wavfile read?

Tags: python, áudio

Olá, 
 Eu tenho utilizado o scipy.io.wavfile.read para abrir os arquivos de áudio disponibilizados em: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_information_tones.
 Eu converto os arquivos para wav usando o VLC. Em tese os tons deveriam estar entre as frequências 913 e 1776. Mas, ao ler o arquivo, os dados retornados sobem a mais de 6000 Hz. Então, minha curiosidade é:

1. Eu estou interpretando os dados retornados corretamente? São inteiros de 16bits (2 bytes).
2. Existe outra forma de obter essas frequências?

Eu já postei outra questão mostrando como eu queria usar isso, mas estou achando que estou interpretando os dados erroneamente. ([Tons SIT usando Python ou C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/109807/tons-sit-usando-python-ou-c/110016#110016))

[EDIT] Esse é o rascunho do código que estou utilizando para fazer os testes: http://pastebin.com/yvng2VE8

[EDIT] Estou querendo verificar se ocorreram os tons em arquivos como esse: [recording.wav](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/106738286/recording.wav).
Para isso estou utilizando esses dois arquivos abaixo como prova primeiro, para validar o conceito e o detector e depois tentar rodar ele no arquivo acima. [IC_SIT.wav](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/106738286/IC_SIT.wav) e [RO'_SIT.wav](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/106738286/RO'_SIT.wav)

Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Pode editar a pergunta e colocar o código que você está usando para ler o arquivo e encontrar a frequência de 6000 Hz? Talvez fique mais fácil para ajudar

Comment: Qual algoritmo você está usando para encontrar as frequências ?

Comment: Coloque o arquivo de áudio .wav online em algum lugar para eu escutar e analisar também.

Comment: Olá, @ederwander, estou querendo verificar se ocorreram os tons em arquivos como esse: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/106738286/recording.wav

Para isso, estou utilizando esses dois arquivos abaixo como prova primeiro, para validar o conceito e o detector e depois tentar rodar ele no arquivo acima.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/106738286/IC_SIT.wav
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/106738286/RO'_SIT.wav

Comment: Eu fiz análises no domínio do tempo e frequência no arquivo RO' SIT.wav, da uma olhada na minha resposta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bom eu vou tentar explicar alguns conceitos sem entrar na profunda matemática envolvida.

Primeiro `scipy.io.wavfile.read` vai te retornar a amplitude do sinal em `short int`, você pode manipular estes valores para mudar o volume do seu áudio, deixar em mudo, aumentar, diminuir. O valor da amplitude deve ser utilizado por você para poder achar suas frequências.

O @jsbueno te deu uma boa abordagem, tenho algumas considerações sobre a definição de frequência.

> O número de idas e vindas dessa membrana do alto-falante por segundo é
>   que representa a frequência: ou seja - cada vez que esses números
>   passam de uma série acendente para uma descendente e depois para uma
>   acendente de volta, se conta um "ciclo" - se essa descida e subida dos
>   números leva 441 números para acontecer numa onda amostrada em 44100
>   herts, isso significa que a frequência naquele ponto é de 100 hertz
>   (em 1 segundo, você terá 100 picos de onda - ou ciclos).

Bom eu entendi o que você quis dizer mas ficou um pouco confuso, definir frequências como sendo picos, subidas e descidas é simplista de mais, isso pode ser verdade para sinais puros sem interferências (senoidais) o que é raro no mundo real, senoides enviadas como tons durante uma ligação sofrem ruídos, atenuações, as operadoras adoram colocar de proposito um ruido branco para dar uma sensação de que a linha não esta muda,etc,etc,etc. Freqüência é sinônimo de periodicidade, pense em periodicidade como um intervalo de tempo em que determinada ocorrência se repete;

Com o tempo só de olhar o plot da amplitude de um sinal você será capaz de quase instantaneamente definir a frequência deste sinal no domínio do tempo, o que pode ser computacionalmente complexo em alguns casos. vamos a um exemplo de uma senoide a 100hz amostrado a 44100hz.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ai esta um tom puro sem interferências, é fácil de visualizar onde um período se repete a partir do ponto `x,y=0` eu marquei o eixo `x` exatamente na posição `441` que é onde um ciclo=período se repete, isso te dá 100hz de frequência pra esse sinal `44100/441=100hz`

Pois bem vamos complicar um pouco, que tal pegar 100hz sem ser uma senoide, fui neste site e peguei este arquivo de áudio [aqui](http://www.physics.umd.edu/~reberg/outreach/QOTW/arch17/q328.htm)

Dá uma olhada como já é mais complexo encontrar onde um período se repete:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O audio foi amostrado em 48000hz, marquei a olho nú que no eixo `x 477` é onde um período se repete `48000/477=±100hz` para ser exato = 100.6289hz

Isso vai te dar uma ideia de como as coisas podem se complicar quando um sinal vem cheio de ruídos e atenuações, note que quando um período se repete não é preciso que ele seja exatamente igual, no mundo real nunca vai ser devido as interferências, OK o @jsbueno te falou sobre o cruzamento de 0 no eixo X (zero crossing), de fato esse é um método de conseguir frequências e realmente é bem rudimentar, as maneiras mais inteligentes de se achar frequências no domínio do tempo envolvem auto-correlação dá uma lida em técnicas como AMDF (Average Magnitude Difference Function).

Só por curiosidade eu peguei o exemplo "RO' SIT", vamos fazer uma análise no domínio do tempo do áudio, segundo o wiki estas frequências precisam ser `(low) 913.8 Hz (high) 1428.5 Hz (low) 1776.7 Hz`. Ai está o plot do audio:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A primeira coisa que eu notei é que existe um fade in/fade out concatenando cada frequência, isso foi feito para não acontecer estralos no áudio entre as transições de frequências, vamos dar um zoom nas primeiras 1024 amostras e tentar achar a frequência:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora dá pra ver claramente o fade-in (efeito de aparecimento gradual de som), ele começa do zero e vai aumentando a amplitude do sinal, mais uma vez a olho nú eu consigo ver mais ou menos onde o período está, marquei o `x=48`, este arquivo está amostrado em `44100hz` portando `44100/48=918.7500hz`, eu andei os primeiros 1024 (posição do vetor 1 até 1024) samples do arquivo, vamos caminhar para os próximos 1024 (posição do vetor 1024 até 2048):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Desta vez a olho nú eu marquei o `x=49`, portando `44100/49=900hz`, é ai que eu queria chegar olha como a diferença de um inteiro 48 para 49 té dá mais de `18hz` de diferença, por tanto um algoritmo no domínio do tempo tem que ser esperto o suficiente para achar o período de modo fracional, mas vamos lá isso é um exemplo a olho pra você entender como encontrar frequências, vamos pular para o próximo bloco e tentar achar algo perto da próxima frequência esperada (1428.5hz):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Desta vez marquei o `x=32` = `1378hz`.

Vou para 1024 amostras em algum ponto no ultimo pedaço, desta vez vamos esperar uma frequência próximo de 1776.7 Hz:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pronto `x=25` =  `1764hz`

Só falamos de como conseguir frequências no domínio do tempo você provavelmente não vai querer ir por este caminho, para o que você precisa goertzel continua sendo a melhor escolha.

Ai você me pergunta como eu consigo achar as frequências no domínio da frequência, pois bem, mais uma vez sem entrar em modelos matemáticos podemos simplificar e dizer que Fourier conseguiu provar que toda forma de onda periódica pode ser decomposta em ondas senoidais,  cada componente espectral representa uma senoide, quanto mais componentes mais preciso a decomposição das ondas em senoides será (ordem de resolução), porém isso vai te custar muito mais processamento matemático.

Tendo isso em mãos você saberá em qual componente espectral esperar suas frequências, vamos imaginar que você gere `4096` componentes espectrais, isso te daria uma ordem de resolução = 44100/ 4096 = `10,7666015625hz`, isso quer dizer que a precisão de cada componente está perto de 11hz de diferença, a grosso modo você pode estar errando uma frequência na exatidão de 11hz em cada um dos 4096 componentes, antes disso você tem que saber que existe um teorema chamado [Nyquist](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teorema_de_Nyquist), ele define que para reconstruir um sinal com mínimo de perda de informação a frequência amostrada deve ser igual ou maior a duas vezes a maior frequência do espectro desse sinal, se nossa frequência de amostragem é 44100hz então a maior frequência possível dentro deste sinal vai ser `44100/2=22050hz`, mas e ai como saber quais frequências eu vou ter em cada componente espectral da série fourier:

```
  componente 1 -> 10,7666015625000hz

  componente 2 -> 21,5332031250000hz

  componente 3 -> 32,2998046875000hz

  componente 4 -> 43,0664062500000hz

  componente 5 -> 53,8330078125000hz

    …

    …

    …

  componente  2047 -> 22039,2333984375hz

  componente  2048 – > 22050hz
```

Opa chegamos no componente 2048 que é a máxima frequência permitida pelo teorema de Nyquist.

No caso da sua necessidade a frequência `913.8hz`, estaria no componente `85`, para o 84 ele estaria abaixo da frequência e o 86 acima.

```
>> 10.7666 * 84

ans =

  904.3944

>> 10.7666 * 85

ans =

  915.1610


>> 10.7666 * 86

ans =

  925.9276
```

Goertzel estaria olhando diretamente para o componente que você precisa e não para todos os outros 2048 componentes, olha o ganho computacional absurdo que ele te dá.

Segue uma brincadeira em python que mostra as frequencias do arquivo de áudio inteiro ainda usando o exemplo "RO' SIT", um detalhe usei `wave.open` é nativo do python mas vai retornar os mesmos dados do scipy:

```
import wave
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

wf = wave.open('C:\Users\ederwander\Desktop\RO_SIT.wav', 'rb')
sinal = wf.readframes(-1)

Amplitude = np.fromstring(sinal, dtype=np.int16)
AmplitudeJanelada=Amplitude*np.hamming(len(Amplitude)); 
Fourier=abs(np.fft.rfft(AmplitudeJanelada))


NyquistTeorema = (wf.getframerate() / 2)

MinFrequencia=NyquistTeorema / (len(Amplitude) / 2);

Frequencias=np.linspace(MinFrequencia, NyquistTeorema, num=(len(Amplitude) / 2))

plt.figure(1)
plt.title('Fourier')
plt.plot(Frequencias,Fourier[0:len(Frequencias)])


plt.figure(2)
plt.title('Fourier Zoom')
plt.plot(Frequencias[800:2000],Fourier[800:2000])


plt.show()
```

Eu usei o tamanho do arquivo de audio inteiro isso dá uma resolução de  `44100/45506 =  0.9691hz`, também só utilizei a parte real de Fourier.

O primeiro plot mostra todos os componentes espectrais retornados por Fourier:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ficou um pouco difícil de ver as frequências eu dei um zoom no segundo plot no código, você vai ver que vai de 800hz até 2000hz que é mais ou menos a zona de frequência de seu interesse.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se você usar um algoritmo que encontre somente picos neste plot você vai perceber que o primeiro pico acontece na frequencia 913.89hz o segundo em 1428.29hz, e o terceiro em 1776.36hz, realmente bate com as frequências do Wiki.

Comment: fantástico. Muito obrigado. Com a resposta da outra pergunta, já deu pra ter MUITO embasamento pra prosseguir.
Uma última pergunta: a duração da frequência não é importante, então, para esse caso de estudo, não é? Já que, ela existe e a ordem ocorre exatamente como no link do wiki, correto? Ou há a necessidade de eu tentar descobrir a duração dela?

Comment: @DiogoPaschoal, para o seu caso é óbvio q a duração vai ser importante, a quantidade de amostras (duração) q você vai enviar para fourier ou goertzel junto com a resposta de cada frequência vai definir qual será o seu SIT, como eu te disse Goertzel é a maneira mais sábia de solucionar o seu problema, as análises aqui foram pra demonstrar alguns conceitos no domínio do tempo e frequência na qual você vai se deparar, a minha resposta fugiu bastante do escopo da sua pergunta, se tiver mais duvidas abra uma nova pergunta sobre Fourier/Goertzel e duração que eu posso tentar formular uma resposta.

Answer (score 3):

Os dados de uma onda sonora descomprimida, tal como representada num arquivo ".wav", (e disponiblizados num array após a leitura) não simbolizam a frequência naquela ponto, e sim, a amplitude - isso é, a "posição" da onda sonora em cada momento do tempo.

Em termos físicos, é esse número que, pode, por exemplo, ser usado para posicionar uma membrana que empurra o ar (como acontece num alto-falante)  0 num .wav de 16 bits, cada dado desses, chamado de amostra (sample) em inglês, representa diretamente a posição da membrana do alto-falante (ou, "a pressão do ar") em cada momento do tempo - não a frequência - esse número pode ir de -2**15 até 2**15-1 (32767) - esse deslocamento -32000 - significa em termos físicos a máxima voltagem no sinal de áudio naquequele momento - que implica em máximo deslocamento da membrana do alto-falante.

. A onda sonora é representada numericamente, de acordo com o número de amostras por segundo. Se for um arquivo de 44100 amostras por segundo (a função `scipy.io.wavfile.read` devolve esse número como primeiro elemento da tupla retornada) quer dizer que 44100 dos números que compõe o array serão usados em um segundo - cada um dos 44100 números indicando uma posição da membrana do alto-falante.  O número de idas e vindas dessa membrana do alto-falante por segundo é que representa a frequência: ou seja - cada vez que esses números passam de uma série acendente para uma descendente e depois para uma acendente de volta, se conta um "ciclo" - se essa descida e súbida dos números leva 441 números para acontecer numa onda amostrada em 44100 herts, isso significa que a frequência naquele ponto é de 100 hertz (em 1 segundo, você terá 100 picos de onda - ou ciclos).

Eu peguei um dos arquivos que você indicou, e criei a amostragem com 44100Hz (pelo visto, um exagero - parece que a amostragem original era só de 8000Hz) - mas então, os dados que tenho na posição 0 até a 100 são:

```
array([-4371, -5314, -6153, -6870, -7452, -7888, -8169, -8289, -8246,
       -8040, -7676, -7161, -6506, -5722, -4825, -3834, -2767, -1646,
        -493,   670,  1820,  2934,  3989,  4967,  5846,  6610,  7244,
        7735,  8074,  8255,  8273,  8128,  7824,  7366,  6763,  6027,
        5173,  4218,  3179,  2079,   937,  -222, -1378, -2506, -3585,
       -4594, -5512, -6323, -7009, -7557, -7957, -8201, -8283, -8203,
       -7961, -7563, -7016, -6331, -5521, -4602, -3593, -2513, -1383,
        -226,   935,  2079,  3181,  4221,  5178,  6033,  6769,  7372,
        7829,  8132,  8276,  8256,  8073,  7732,  7238,  6602,  5837,
        4956,  3978,  2922,  1809,   660,  -501, -1653, -2771, -3835,
       -4823, -5716, -6497, -7150, -7662, -8024, -8228, -8270, -8150, -7869], dtype=int16)
```

podemos ver que os números cumprem nesse intervalo tem aproximadamente 2 picos perto do +8000 - ou seja, aproximadamente 1 ciclo a cada 50 amostras, a 44100 amostras por segundo - o que equivale a uma frequência de cerca de 880Hz  - esse cálculo o cálculo feito a grosso modo mostra a ordem de grandeza - se pegarmos os picos exatos, os números 8273 na posição 30, e  8276 na posição 76 - 44 amostras. 44100 amostras/s / 44 amostras/ciclo e temos 1002 ciclos/s  - bem dentro da sua faixa desejada.

Eu não entendo muito de processamento de sinais e localização de frequências - certamente o scipy tem funções que podem fazer a análise de frequências nesses dados e devolver uma série de frequências ao longo do som, como parece ser seu objetivo.

Mas, caso isso seja mais complexo do que você precisa, é possível fazer uma função de análise grosseira, que devolva todos os intervalos entre cada vez que a amplitude cruza a posição 0, por exemplo, e a partir daí, dar a frequência predominante em vários pontos do áudio.

Uma função pode contar a duração de cada ciclo de onda no áudio, e uma outra anota cada posição (em segundos) e a frequência onde a duração dos ciclos mudou de forma mais ou menos consistente. È muito diferente e cru perto do tratamento matemático de frequências possível, mas talvez possa ser refinado o suficiente para reconhecer esse tipo de arquivo que você quer tratar:

```
import numpy as np
from __future__ import division


def count_peak_distances(data):
    res =  []
    previous = 0
    count = 0
    for i, sample in enumerate(data):
        if previous > 0 and sample < 0:
            res.append((i, count))
            count = 0
        previous = sample
        count += 1
    return res[1:]


def describe_wave(data, frequency):
    # allow for a frequency distortion of 
    # 0.2%  before counting as a tune-change-point
    delta = 0.0001 * frequency
    res = []
    last_cicle_size = 0
    last_changed_position = -1
    for sample_position, cicle_size in count_peak_distances(data):
        if not (last_cicle_size - delta < cicle_size < last_cicle_size + delta):
            values =  sample_position /  frequency, frequency / cicle_size
            # avoid anotating short frequency peaks at frequency boundaries
            if values[0] - last_changed_position > 0.01:
                res.append(values)
                last_changed_position = values[0]
            else:
                res[-1] = values
            last_cicle_size = cicle_size
    return res
```

jogando os dados do meu arquivo .wav, mono, de 44100 hertz obtenho esses tempos em segundos onde acontecem mudanças de frequências (e as respectivas frequências) dentro do arquivo. Tenha em mente que essas funções não tratam do "silêncio" no arquivo (porçoes od arquivo onde a amplitude é baixa) portanto, as faixas de silêncio ficam com frequências espúrias:

```
In [121]: describe_wave(d1, 44100)
Out[121]: 
[(0.0019501133786848073, 980.0),
 (0.2625170068027211, 1378.125),
 (0.6432426303854876, 1764.0),
 (1.0228798185941044, 2004.5454545454545),
 (3.0029931972789115, 980.0),
 (3.2787755102040816, 1378.125),
 (3.659501133786848, 1764.0),
 (3.7337868480725622, 1764.0),
 (4.03984126984127, 1470.0)]
```

Comment: Obrigado, @jsbueno. Me ajudou a entender os dados retornados pela função. Um colega já tinha me dito também pra ver as distâncias entre os picos.