# Como funciona o StdAudio em java?

Tags: java, áudio

Eu estou tentando ler as frequencias de um audio, eu passei um dia inteiro tendando entender FFT e terminei sabendo menos do que quando eu comecei.
Mas no fim eu achei a StdAudio no java. 
esse dae: https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/StdAudio.java.html.

So que ue ainda não entendi como funciona esse read dele, alguem sabe me dizer o que exatamente a função read esta retornando? Por que eu preciso da frequencia mas a função retorna um array de double com valores entre -1 e 1 e eu ainda não entendi o que isso significa. Se for frequencia alguem sabe me dizer como transformar e um valor em hz?

Answer (score 3):

@RafaelGuasselli capturar frequência de um áudio não é algo trivial, está tentando fazer o que exatamente, afinador de guitarra ou algo parecido ?

A função `read` do código apenas retorna as amostras do áudio em float point, se plotar os resultados vai conseguir enxergar a forma de onda do áudio lido, não tem nada no código que você mostrou tentando se quer chegar perto de capturar a frequência.

Fast Fourier Transform (FFT) - posso resumir de uma maneira mais simples possível que utilizamos essa transformada para no princípio decompor um sinal no domínio de tempo para o domínio da frequência, isso quer dizer que conseguimos abrir um espectro de todas as frequências existentes, isso não se resume a apenas áudio, pode ser utilizado para qualquer dado que vc tenha no domínio do tempo, uma planilha com dados de vendas por exemplo, vc poderia tentar encontrar padrões de períodos que teve mais vendas...

Mas voltando a falar sobre áudio, se estiver tentando fazer algum afinador ou capturar frequências de voz o FFT não é muito recomendado, se estiver interessado na frequência física em sí a FFT pode ser válida, se tiver interessado em por exemplo saber qual é a escala de afinação de uma voz ou instrumento é pouco recomendado a utilização pura do FFT para esse fim, tem uma área mt doida chamada `psicoacústica`, isso define como nosso cérebro interpreta um som, muitas vezes um som com uma frequência fisicamente bem definida pode parecer diferente para os nossos ouvidos, e é ai que o FFT falha miseravelmente, não em todos os casos mas em alguns casos, a junção da frequência fundamental com os harmônicos definem sua real tonalidade para os nossos ouvidos, ao usar a FFT as "pessoas" ignoram os harmônicos e apenas olham qual foi o maior pico retornado pela FFT e apenas definem isso como frequência fundamental de um som ...

Claro o tamanho da FFT tem total relação com a ordem de resolução dos componentes retornados, quanto menor o tamanho da FFT maior será a ordem de resolução e menos preciso será o algoritmo ...

Tem mt coisa, fica complicado escrever sem saber o que vc tá tentando fazer e os motivos pelos quais quer capturar frequências...

Existem também algorítimos para capturar frequências no domínio do tempo (algoritmos baseados em autocorrelação)

**Perca um tempo lendo essas minhas respostas:**

1. A partir da forma de onda como saber a frequência, apenas olhando e encontrando o período, nomes de algoritmos para encontrar frequências de brinde [(aqui)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/112857/o-que-s%C3%A3o-os-dados-obtidos-por-scipy-io-wavfile-read)
2. Exemplos em Python de como usar autocorrelação no domínio do tempo e frequência para conseguir frequências ([aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/271598/fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-autocorrela%C3%A7ao-no-python/301225#301225))
3. Tudo que você precisa saber sobre como a FFT mapeia os componentes espectrais baseado no tamanho do FFT enviado + um monte de nomes de técnicas conhecidas para  capturar frequências + código meu em java open source no tarsos ([aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/249250/obter-a-frequencia-a-partir-de-um-vetor-no-dominio-da-frequencia/253278#253278))

Lembrando que periodicidade/frequência são sinônimos, se você souber em qual período algo se repete você saberá a frequência...

O código postado pelo @Scarabelo só vai retornar o espectro do áudio, para conseguir qual é a frequência dominante você tem que encontrar qual é a posição do maior pico do componente retornado (vai aprender como fazer isso no link `3` acima, código em python no link `2` no ultimo algoritmo)

Isso tudo só é valido para sons monofônicos se estiver falando de captura de frequências para sons polifônicos a coisa vai para um patamar completamente diferente e eu nem sei por onde começar rsrsrs

Comment: +1 pela psicoacústica, fiquei sabendo mais essa!

Comment: Resumindo tudo

Meu objetivo era achar quais notas eram tocadas em uma musica.
Mas meio que o problema do meu projeto ja foi contornado, so vou continuar porque agora isso dae é meu novo desafio.

//Vai ser meio longo mais vou explicar tudo abaixo

Isso é pra um projeto de fisica que eu e uns colegas decidimos tentar achar uma relação entre atributos fisicos da musica e as emoções, dae a ideia "mais simples"(não ta sendo nem um pouco simples ksksk)

Comment: seria perguntar sobre musicas que causassem algumas emoções em um formulario para varias pessoas, analisar as notas de cada musica, e os dados da nota que tivessem um desvio padrão baixo entre todas as musicas de uma mesma emoção de certa forma seriam mais provaveis de ter relação.

No inicio eu tinha feito um programa que lia midi. So que as musicas que as pessoas mandaram não tinha quase nenhuma em midi e pelo que eu vi ia ser muito dificil converte.

Comment: Atualmente o problema do projeto ta resolvido porque nos invertemos a pesquisa. Agora nos damos algumas musicas especificas que nos ja tinhamos o midi e perguntavamos a emoção
Mas de qualquer forma vou continuar até conseguir fazer esse programa de audio em outros formatos alem de midi. O problema mesmo é que os sites que falam disso ta muito separado, são muitas coisas de varias areas que eu tenho que entender pra depois juntar tudo junto. To precisando agora meio que montar uma arvore de skill pra eu conseguir me achar no que eu tenho q estudar pra conseguir fazer esse programa do zero.

Answer (score 0):

Fussando um pouco nas internets (achei interessante seu questionamento relacionado a FFT) achei um algorítimo que executa o FFT e discrimina o conteúdo de cada variável, talves te ajude:

Fonte do código: https://github.com/hendriks73/jipes/blob/master/src/main/java/com/tagtraum/jipes/math/FFTFactory.java

```java
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class AudioLED {

    private static final float NORMALIZATION_FACTOR_2_BYTES = Short.MAX_VALUE + 1.0f;

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        // use only 1 channel, to make this easier
        final AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, 44100, 16, 1, 2, 44100, false);
        final DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);
        final TargetDataLine targetLine = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        targetLine.open();
        targetLine.start();
        final AudioInputStream audioStream = new AudioInputStream(targetLine);

        final byte[] buf = new byte[256]; // <--- increase this for higher frequency resolution
        final int numberOfSamples = buf.length / format.getFrameSize();
        final JavaFFT fft = new JavaFFT(numberOfSamples);
        while (true) {
            // in real impl, don't just ignore how many bytes you read
            audioStream.read(buf);
            // the stream represents each sample as two bytes -> decode
            final float[] samples = decode(buf, format);
            final float[][] transformed = fft.transform(samples);
            final float[] realPart = transformed[0];
            final float[] imaginaryPart = transformed[1];
            final double[] magnitudes = toMagnitudes(realPart, imaginaryPart);

            // do something with magnitudes...
        }
    }

    private static float[] decode(final byte[] buf, final AudioFormat format) {
        final float[] fbuf = new float[buf.length / format.getFrameSize()];
        for (int pos = 0; pos < buf.length; pos += format.getFrameSize()) {
            final int sample = format.isBigEndian()
                    ? byteToIntBigEndian(buf, pos, format.getFrameSize())
                    : byteToIntLittleEndian(buf, pos, format.getFrameSize());
            // normalize to [0,1] (not strictly necessary, but makes things easier)
            fbuf[pos / format.getFrameSize()] = sample / NORMALIZATION_FACTOR_2_BYTES;
        }
        return fbuf;
    }

    private static double[] toMagnitudes(final float[] realPart, final float[] imaginaryPart) {
        final double[] powers = new double[realPart.length / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < powers.length; i++) {
            powers[i] = Math.sqrt(realPart[i] * realPart[i] + imaginaryPart[i] * imaginaryPart[i]);
        }
        return powers;
    }

    private static int byteToIntLittleEndian(final byte[] buf, final int offset, final int bytesPerSample) {
        int sample = 0;
        for (int byteIndex = 0; byteIndex < bytesPerSample; byteIndex++) {
            final int aByte = buf[offset + byteIndex] & 0xff;
            sample += aByte << 8 * (byteIndex);
        }
        return sample;
    }

    private static int byteToIntBigEndian(final byte[] buf, final int offset, final int bytesPerSample) {
        int sample = 0;
        for (int byteIndex = 0; byteIndex < bytesPerSample; byteIndex++) {
            final int aByte = buf[offset + byteIndex] & 0xff;
            sample += aByte << (8 * (bytesPerSample - byteIndex - 1));
        }
        return sample;
    }

}
```

Comment: ok, to tentando usar esse codigo mas eu ainda to muito perdido.

Comment: 1-qual a interferencia do tamanho do buf? 
Quando eu mudo ele os valores simplesmente se alteram e eu ainda não entendo o porquê.
2-O que exatamente deveriam ser as magnitudes?
3-Quando exatamente eu paro esse while(true)?

Comment: 4-Eu preciso usar (linha:1,2,3,4,5[a partir do primeiro comentario da main])  se eu ler o audio direto na stream?